# View chart data by week/month in Google Analytics 4 / GA4

Tags: google-analytics

Such a simple thing, but as with so many things I can't find this now in GA4.

I just want to view the standard acquisition (views) figures in their default line graphs, but not with data by day, but by month.

Is this possible?

Comment: I can't post answers. But for GA4: Click 'Explore' (left sidebar) -> Freeform, Line Chart, Granularity set to "Week"

Answer (score 4):

According to Google as of 8-14-23 "Currently, you can only view daily data, not weekly or monthly data."

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/13412290?hl=en

[image]

Comment: I'm NOT believing that they've made such thing. Even when I can confirm this is 100% true. I've been looking for this for two months not even considering that this could have been excluded from GA.

Comment: Agreed, it is unconscionable that this feature would be removed, as it is one of the most important things at-a-glance. If this feature was removed, the product is broken and it is time to migrate. Because anyone who would remove such a feature would be completely incompetent at creating a quality product: if this feature was removed intentionally, you can guarantee a long list of other things have also been broken.

Comment: You have to re-create the view. Here's a guide https://infotrust.com/articles/recreating-universal-analytics-reports-in-ga4-top-acquisition-reports/

Answer (score 2):

In a default report (like Acquisition > Acquisition overview) if you try selecting the date range, it'll initially just show data by day.

But if you **first toggle the date range to "last 12 months"** and **then select a specific date range** that starts on a Sunday and ends on a Saturday, it'll show the data broken down by week.

(This is an odd, hidden way to get data aggregated by week in the default reports.)

If you add a segment (like Session default channel group = Organic search), it'll go back to just having data per day, but you can change it back to data by week by toggling to "last 12 months" again before switching it to the date range you actually want to see.

Answer (score 1):

I may be misunderstanding your question, as my User Acquisition Report shows Week by default.  If you're looking for By Month in the built in User Acquisition Report, you'll probably have to create a custom report.

If you're asking about custom reports, you can choose Month and Week from the Granularity Menu.  I don't have enough data yet in my GA4 account to see months (my Month's option is there but greyed out), but I definitely have access to by Week.

**GA 4 Line Graph Settings in a Custom Report:**

[image]

**And the resulting graph in a Custom Report:**
[image]

Comment: User Acquisition report shows daily for me; not weekly.

Comment: The icons are totally dissimilar from what I'm seeing on my GA4 user acquisition page. You have six icons in a 3x2 grid, mine has only 4 in a 4x1 grid. I don't see the "visualization" heading nor the "segment comparisons" nor "granularity". How are you even finding this page? I went on the left to Acquisition -> User acquisition. I don't see any other way to get a similar report.

Comment: @Trebor, what exactly is a “Custom Report” in this context? When searching in the GA4 interface itself and when googling, I find references to “customizing reports”, but very few references to the term Custom Report. The article https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10445879 mentions that one can have up to “150 custom reports” and then goes on to talk about customizing “detail reports”. I tried creating one of those, but it only lets me choose chart types (line, bar etc), not granularity or any other chart-related settings.

Comment: @OttoG pretty sure this is an Exploration, i.e. from Explore on the left nav bar. The downside of these is that there is a limit to the date range that can be used, IIRC. It's possible monthly is greyed out for Trebor for this very reason.